# Check arrays matching PHP

Tags: php, arrays, size, matching

So basically I want to check if the user has the groups listen in an array (integers) and return back if he have more than 2 or less than 2 matching in two arrays.

```
if(sizeof(array_diff($gameids,$ggids) > 2)) {
    print "<script>alert('You have more than two games')</script>";
    } else {
    print "<script>alert('You have less than two games')</script>";
   }
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. It looks like you asked a question and then posted the answer. Could you elaborate or possibly adjust your phrasing?

Comment: you need to move the `> 2` over one parenthesis.

Comment: Basically, I want to check if the arrays have two matches in both, if they do I print the first sentence, if not I print the second sentence

Comment: you might be looking for [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) which returns the matching values, as opposed to [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) which returns the non-matching values.

Comment: my lord i'm an idiot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) which returns the matching values, as opposed to [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) which returns the non-matching values.

Also in your example, the `> 2` needs to move over one parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! You just had a parenthesis problem:

```
if(sizeof(array_diff($gameids,$ggids)) > 2) {
    print "<script>alert('You have more than two games')</script>";
} else {
    print "<script>alert('You have less than two games')</script>";
}
```

It's the `sizeof` that you compare to `2`, not the `array_diff`.